# How to set vals to be used in tests?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I've been noticing a lot of repetition to set up each test with Play/specs2. I'm aware that you can create a trait that extends `mutable.Before` and use that to set up tests but any values created there seem to be out of scope for my tests.

What I would like to be able to do is set `val user = User.create("User Name")` in a class or trait before each test runs so I can have access to `user` later on in the test.  How can this be achieved?

```
// SpecificationWithFixtures.scala
package models

import org.specs2.execute.{AsResult, Result}
import org.specs2.mutable._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

abstract class SpecificationWithFixtures extends Specification {
  abstract class WithFakeDB extends WithApplication(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {
    override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = super.around {
      t
    }
  }
}


// UserSpec.scala
package models

import org.junit.runner._
import org.specs2.runner._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class UserSpec extends SpecificationWithFixtures {
  "User.create" should {
    "save user in the database" in new WithFakeDB {
      val user = User.create("User Name")
      // Some test for user
    }
  }

  "User.findAll" should {
    "return a list of all users" in new WithFakeDB {
      val user = User.create("User Name")
      // Another test for user
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is something like:

```scala
def withUser[T](test: User => T): T = test(User create "Username")

// or even more configurable
def withUser[T](name: String)(test: User => T): T = test(User create name)

// Then writing expectations you can do
"User Roger" in withUser("Roger") { 
  roger => // trivial example
    roger.name must_== "Roger"
}

// or even
"User" in withUser("John") {
  _.name must_== "John"
}
```

This kind of loan pattern is useful writing specs2.

In previous example it's user per expectation (`in`), but it can be used for a group of expectations (`should`, `>>`), or for all.

```scala
"User" should withUser("xyz") {
  "exp1" in { ??? }
}
```